# PyCharm SonarLint How to view all issues across all files?

Tags: python, pycharm, sonarqube, sonarlint

In Pycharm, you can view the SonarLint issues in a single file by opening the file and clicking on the SonarLint tab on the bottom of the IDE.

However, this only shows the issues for a single file.

How can you view all the SonarLint issues across all files within a single project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project panel, right click on the root directory, then navigate through Sonar Lint>Analyze with Sonar Lint.